# How to get the music disc 11 without being in creative or /give command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering how can we get that special disc named "11" in Minecraft without any cheat. Do we have to kill some monsters, look for hidden chests ???

Can we get that disc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Music Disc 11 is currently not available through normal game play. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Music_Discs)

Comment: You have written a general guide to Music Discs. The question is specifically about the "11" disc which is known to be unavailable by the means you have covered.

Comment: Yup, just checked and thought the last disc I got was 11.. Tis not the case, answer updated to This is currently not available through normal gameplay.

Comment: James, the one you got was probably "stal"

Answer (score 0):

If a skeleton shoots a creeper, and kills it, the creeper will drop its usual loot AND one of the music discs. This is chosen at random, but only the other 10. Some chests in dungeons have them but still not "11". This leads me to believe Jeb and the team are going to make a special way to find this creepy tune.